# Zend_Service_Twitter and Twitter API 1.1 (ZF 1.12.3)

Tags: zend-framework, twitter

I've upgraded to Zend Framework v1.12.3 because it supports the TwitterAPI v1.1 with Zend_Service_Twitter. Before, I've used the TwitterAPI 1.0 (prior ZF 1.12.3) which works well, but that's gonna [change in march 2013](https://dev.twitter.com/blog/changes-coming-to-twitter-api).

If I call the TwitterAPI v1.1 with the following ZF 1.12.3 code, I keep getting a strange error which I can't explain to myself:

Code:

```
     $twitterService = new Zend_Service_Twitter(array(
            'consumerKey'    => $this->config['consumerKey'],
            'consumerSecret' => $this->config['consumerSecret'],
            'username'       => $twitterVO->getTwitterUserName(),
            'accessToken'    => $accessToken // unserialized object
));

 $response = $twitterService->statusesUpdate("TEST");
```

And that's the error which I get. It doesn't matter which function I call (in this case it's statusesUpdate("Test")):

[image]

The message is "Invalid chunk size "" unable to read chunked body". The "type" attribute within the array shows a "->". That's also a bit suspect but I couldn't find out where it comes from.

Does anyone have a working example with Zend Framework 1.12.3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since ZF 1.12, the Twitter app Oauth parameters can be given in the Zend_Service_Twitter constructor, but consumerKey and consumerSecret must go under the "oauthOptions" array.

This works for me:

```
$accessToken = new Zend_Oauth_Token_Access();
$accessToken->setToken('YourAccessToken');
$accessToken->setTokenSecret('YourAccessTokenSecret');

$twitter = new Zend_Service_Twitter(
    array(
        'username' => 'YourUsername',
        'accessToken' => $accessToken,
        'oauthOptions' => array(
            'consumerKey' => 'YourConsumerKey',
            'consumerSecret' => 'YourConsumerSecret'
        )
    )
);

$result = $twitter->statusesUserTimeline('TEST');
```

Comment: Thanks, arraintxo. That's the solution!